# tortoisehg on ubuntu - how to hide Ques overlay icons showing on all files and folders

Tags: ubuntu, mercurial, icons, ubuntu-12.04, tortoisehg

I installed Tortoisehg on ubuntu for Mercurial. But after installation all the files and folders of Desktop , home , etc are having a question icon overlay on it.
Which is very irritating.
Can anyone guide it to how to disable the overlay icon appearing from all the files anf folders.
Below is the link to the image - 108.163.162.132/Test/Desktop.png

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a mercurial repository in your home directory (i.e.: you've run `hg init` on your `~`).  From this point you seem to have two options:

In the case that you **accidentally initialized** your **home** as a **mercurial repository**, you can solve that by removing the `.hg` folder from your home:

```
$ rm  -r  ~/.hg
```

Ooor, in the case that you **really want** a repository in your **home** (a "dotfiles" repo, maybe?), you can just "add everything" to you `~/.hgignore`:

```
syntax: glob
*
```

That'll make everything untracked, except whichever files you add explictly.